# Can I gitignore the .tmcRefac and .tpr files in TwinCAT?

Tags: twincat

Whenever you refactor a TwinCAT project, it creates a .tmcRefac file. After building this file gets converted into a .tpr file. What are these files exactly and can I add them to my .gitignore file?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

The .tmcRefac can be ignored as also mentioned [here](https://alltwincat.com/2019/12/02/gitignore-for-twincat/) and it was included in the [official GitHub gitignore for TwinCAT](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TwinCAT3.gitignore). The .tpr file can't be ignored, because it contains important information about the rename history for the System Manager.

### Long answer

The .tmcRefac file contains information about which variable got renamed to what:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Refactors>
  <Renames>
    <RenamedSymbol>
      <Type guid="904700f4-ab78-477a-973a-562c3c32f400">MAIN</Type>
      <From>number1</From>
      <To>number2</To>
    </RenamedSymbol>
  </Renames>
</Refactors>
```

After building the project with TwinCAT 4024.12 this files seems to get removed. However, if you have a [stand alone plc project](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/47020711795124677131.html?id=8693496841604521684), it gets converted into a .tpr file. This .tpr file again contains information about  the refactored variable:

```xml
<TcModuleRefactorInfos RefactorCnt="1">
  <TcModuleRefactorInfo RefactorCnt="1" DateTime="2021-11-11T10:46:12">
    <Renames>
      <RenameSymbol>
        <From>MAIN.number1</From>
        <To>MAIN.number2</To>
      </RenameSymbol>
    </Renames>
  </TcModuleRefactorInfo>
</TcModuleRefactorInfos>
```

Beckhoff support says about this file:

> The .tpr file is required to save the rename history of I/O variables in a stand-alone PLC project, since the PLC project and the System Manager are not in the same project. I don't think you should ignore the file as it is relevant to the rename history.

### Bug

If you're running TwinCAT 4024.10-4024.12 there can be a [bug](https://github.com/Roald87/TwinCatChangelog/blob/main/tc3_changelog.md#bug-fix) which crashes Visual Studio/XAE when a .tpr file is present. Solution is to upgrade to > 4024.15.

Comment: I've also only recently noticed the .TPR files, not because of Version control, but mainly because XAE complains about missing the file when deploying. However I have noticed no issues appearing from this after deployment. 

Were you able to at least figure out where TPR files are stored? I've had a look but could not figure that one out. 
And now its a matter of waiting a year or so for that merge request to get....

Comment: @Steve the .tpr file is stored in the same folder as the .plcproj and .tmc file. We've sometimes had issues that visual studio/XAE crashed when the .tpr was present. However, I couldn't recreate this behavior in a new project. Furthermore it doesn't always crash :shrug:.

Comment: Any information from Beckhoff of whether this should be handled in version control or not?

Comment: @Jakob No I haven't yet. So far I haven't noticed issues when removing it. I'll check with support next week.